# Angular 2 routes with same URL?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Like Angular UI Router is it possible to have multiple routes with same URL in Angular2? e.g following two routes:

```
{ path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent} ,
{ path: '/home', name: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
```

Currently, having error in the console for conflicting routes.

Comment: so wich of the two components would you expect angular to render if you go to that route?

Comment: Probably last one :). Actually, I got your point. But its like UI-Router provides having multiple states having a prent linked to same URL.

Comment: I think it might be easier to say what's the functionality you need or add an example of how'd you do it in ui-router

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AuxRoute` if you want `ui-router` style named `ui-view`.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/AuxRoute-class.html

Also, refer this question.
[Is Angular 2 Auxiliary router broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33442363/1433665)

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/JsZbuR?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your Answer @TheKojuEffect. Question was regarding multiple views pointing to same url, but each view acts like a full content page. AuxRoutes is a nice concept BTW.

Answer (score -1):

You can check [Angular2 - two components with the same route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37045548/angular2-two-components-with-the-same-route/37046880#37046880) where possible solutions are discussed to achieve what you are after.

1. Use *ngIf in the template to use different selectors depending on the evaluated condition.

   ```
   <home-logged-in *ngIf="authenticated()"></home-logged-in>
   <home-logged-out *ngIf="!authenticated()"></home-logged-out>
   ```
2. Create custom router-outlet that will load a specific component based on evaluated condition.
3. Redirect to a different route depending on evaluated condition (see the source http://www.captaincodeman.com/2016/03/31/angular2-route-security/)

This list is not conclusive and there might be other ways to achieve what you are looking for.